# Set gravity of custom navigation drawer menu item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-design-library, navigationview

I am adding menu items to navigation drawer pragmatically. All the items are added to the left of navigation view but when I add custom menu item, it adds the item to the right of navigation view.

I am adding menu items pragmatically as below:

```
        Menu menu = mNavigationView.getMenu();
        if (menu == null) return;

        // add home menu
        menu.add(0, 1, Menu.NONE, "Home");

        // add refer menu
        menu.add(0, 2, Menu.NONE, "Refer and Earn");

        // add points menu
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(0, 3, Menu.NONE, null);
        menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.layout_nav_menu_points);

        // add settings menu
        menu.add(0, 4, Menu.NONE, "Settings");

        // add about us menu
        menu.add(0, 5, Menu.NONE, "About us");

        // add logout menu
        menu.add(0, 6, Menu.NONE, "Logout");
```

Below is the code of `layout_nav_menu_points`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Points"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_14" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_5"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_2"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/shape_red_dot" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_2"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_12" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_2"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_2"
            android:text="pt"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_12" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Getting below result:
[image]

**EDIT**: I tried using `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` but getting the same result. Below is the code of `layout_nav_menu_points` using `RelativeLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_points"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Points"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_14" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_5"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_2"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/shape_red_dot" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_points"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_2"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_12" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_2"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_2"
            android:text="pt"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_12" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: Below is the code for `shape_red_dot`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">

        <solid
            android:color="#EC2027" />

        <size
            android:height="10dp"
            android:width="10dp" />
    </shape>
```

Anyone please suggest me how to move that "point" menu to the left like rest of the menu items. Thanks

Comment: why don't you use `RelativeLayout` ?

Comment: Tried RelativeLayout as well but getting the same result.

Comment: show updated code of relative layout

Comment: Updated my question with RelativeLayout implementation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613437/how-to-change-menu-item-gravity-to-right-in-navigationview

Comment: I am getting preview like [this](http://i.imgur.com/vx8x6sz.png) ... you have not shared ur complete code

Answer (score 0):

In your nav_menu_points.. Please do change your layout_gravity and gravity value.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    *** CHANGED CODE
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="left|center_horizontal"
    *** CHANGED CODE ENDS

    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Result Image:

[image]

Difference between gravity and layout_gravity.. 
Well gravity, set your contents gravity (where will it be) whereas, layout_gravity, set your layout's gravity.

Hope it solves the problem. Cheers!

Comment: You can see in my question that I have already tried this code.

Comment: I have changed the gravity and layout_gravity value, marked inside stars..

Comment: I used "start" instead of left for gravity and layout_gravity value to support RTL. So it will be same if I use "left" instead of "start"

Comment: @GaganSingh, used my image to recreate the scenario in my end. came out that.

Comment: This is just preview of layout. I am getting the same preview but when I add this layout to navigation menu, it is appearing on the right side not the left side. Try to set this layout to navigation menu item and see the result.